# Should a semicolon be included when building SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, joomla2.5

When I access mysql from PHP (Joomla) application. Should I include semicolon in SQL queries I send? I.e.

```
$db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM `blah`;");
```

or

```
$db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM `blah`");
```

It might be a case of splitting hairs, but I want to do it consistently - might as well choose a way that is significantly or insignificantly better.

NOTE: Joomla platform code does **not** include semicolons in queries. But I don't trust it.

**UPDATE:** I understand that it works both with and without the semicolon, I am asking if there are any advantages of one way vs the other (except without semicolon being one character shorter).

Comment: I suspect that Joomla does not even support multiple SQL statements...

Answer (score 7):

Semicolons are primarily used to separate multiple queries when dealing with SQL, so no, you do not need to provide a semi-colon.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that the `setQuery()` function is storing these SQL statements individually in an array rather than creating a concatenated string which would run all at once so in this case you do not need semi-colons. You would probably break the matrix trying to run two SELECTs like that.

I can see semi-colons as becoming useful when you want to INSERT many rows into a DB and don't want to call `execute()` thousands of times but then again this syntax would work for that:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

I have primarily used semi-colons when running a sequence of queries in the MySQL Workbench because the cursor needs to be somewhere inside the query you wish to run upon clicking that little execute lightning bolt thingy.

Answer (score 0):

No Semicolons required just the queries will be working fine.